# convert a '$_GET' hex value (string form) to hex int -- how?

Tags: php, hex, decimal

I suspect this might be a duplicate but lord if I can find it.

I need to convert a 'mostly' hex value passed in the `_GET[]` array from string to an actual hex integer.  I say 'mostly' because the hex number passed in is not prepended with the "0x"

The most promising thing I tried and then raised the white flag on this problem was this -- 'azk' is the name of the `GET[]` parameter passed in:

```
   $timeStamp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'azk', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

   //FAILS FOR HEX -->  $test = (int)$timeStamp;
   //FAILS FOR HEX -->  $test =  0 + $timeStamp;

   $retval =  sscanf($timeStamp, '%x', $test);
   var_dump(gettype($test));
   var_dump($test);
```

Here's what happens:   the user passes in an 'azk' value of **531cb6d6**,  which is in fact a hex value but not prepended with the '0x'.

Despite my instructions to `sscanf()` above -- note that I specifically instruct `sscanf()` to convert the value of 'timeStamp' into a hex value by way of the '%x' flag --

-- the `$test` value is shown, via the var_dump's above, as this:

```
   string(7) "integer" int(1394390742)
```

The '1394390742' is *not* hex.  I'm not seeing why, I specifically instruct sscanf to convert to %x hex value, but this '1394390742'  is the base-10 (decimal) version of the base-16 (hexadecimal) value that got passed in, the **531cb6d6** value.  In other words, using "%x" is converting hex to decimal.  Not sure if that is a bug, a setting in the web server ini files somewhere, or a lack of my understanding of "%x".

The `sscanf()` is not all I've tried, this is not exhaustive but I tried things like this, to me the most obvious choice:

```
   // BOTH OF THESE FAIL TO PASS HEX CHARS, BOTH RETURN THIS:   53166
 $timeStamp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'azk', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                             FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_HEX);

 $timeStamp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'azk', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                             FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_HEX);
```

I've looked at a bunch of SO posts, I can't believe this isn't covered, but I can't find it.  If someone knows how to pull this off -- convert a hex value passed by the `_GET` as a string, then convert to a hex value -- I would be in your debt.

Comment: This question has me curious, but I'm a little confused about what you are trying to achieve. Forgive me, but what exactly does a `hex int` look like? What do you *want* `var_dump($test)` to print?

Comment: Succinctly,  $val = (int)$myHexNumAsString is not going to work, I'm going to have to first call hexdec() and then cast.  If you look at my original sample code above, the casting succeeds for a base-10 string and the casting fails for a base-16 string.  For a database of base 16 numbers I have to (1) call hexdec() to convert the hex to decimal, and (2)then I can cast to (int) and do the math.  It would be cool if I could avoid calling hexdec() prior to the math, it would be nice to have a cast like (int-x) or something.  I also have to convert-and-cast the hex input values as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As var_dump shows, the variable $test contains an integer.
PHP is converting the integer back to a decimal string just so it can show it, but the integer itself is not intrinsically decimal, nor hex. Those are just two possible representations of the same value.
If you want to output the value back as an hex string, you can use one of these:

```
echo dechex($test);
printf("%x", $test);
```

Edit: I saw your comments, you don't need to cast as int:
1) hexdec takes the string and returns an integer
2) *...do the math using integers...*
3) dechex takes the result as integer an returns a string

Comment: In other words, sscanf() IS in fact working when I use the "%x" format?  And for whatever reason var_dump() is only capable of displaying base-10 format of any integer, and goes to the trouble of converting my sscanf() "%x" hex (base 16) result to decimal just for displaying it?

Comment: That's right: sscanf with %x parses the string as a sequence of hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hexdec()` function:

```
$timeStamp = hexdec('531cb6d6'); // 1394390742
```

If you want to sanitize the string before using it then you can create your own filter using a callback:

```
$hexTimestamp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'azk', FILTER_CALLBACK, array(
    'options' => function($str) {
        return ctype_xdigit($str) ? $str : 0;
    }
));
$timeStamp = hexdec('531cb6d6');
```

If you not going to use the HEX value then you could also convert it to an integer as part of the sanitizing:

```
$timestamp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'azk', FILTER_CALLBACK, array(
    'options' => function($str) {
        return ctype_xdigit($str) ? hexdec($str) : false;
    }
));
```

**Edit:**

Okay, I am getting confused, I think. You have a HEX input and you want to turn it into a "HEX number". I am not sure I understand what you mean.

If you want the input HEX value to become a "real" PHP HEX value, like `0x531cb6d6`, then you are mistaken about how PHP works. When PHP sees a HEX constant, like `0x531cb6d6`, then it immediately converts it to an integer. PHP does not use HEX numbers; *HEX notation* is just a way of *representing* a number, and it not actually a type of number distinct from integers.

If you want the input HEX value, `"531cb6d6"`, to look like a HEX value with the `0x` prefix then you can just add it: `'0x'.$timeStamp`.

Not sure if I answered your question.

Comment: Not sure but I think you misunderstood; I have a hex string input, and need to convert to a hex number.  Not sure why you're suggesting hexdec() for 2 reasons: (1) I'm actually trying to convert FROM decimal TO hex, because nothing I've tried (yet) will convert the hex string passed in directly to a hex integer;  and (2) both dechex() and hexdec() return strings, and I need the hex string passed in converted to integer form (in hexadecimal).  I very much appreciate your effort, after reading your answer I got excited and tried using 'dechex()' on the sscanf value but dechex returns a string.

Comment: What do you mean by a "hex integer"?

Comment: base 16, not base 10, math.   a + a = 14.  10 + 10 = 20.  Big difference.

Comment: Okay, but PHP does not use base 16. HEX *notation* is just a way of representing numbers. When PHP sees a HEX number, like `0x531cb6d6`, it is immediately converted to an integer.

Comment: That's my take away.  Octal, binary, hex, are only available as strings.  Internally the baseline is base 10 number system.  If you have other base numbers (octal, hex) all the math must be done in base 10 with any conversions my responsibility.   If I have a database of hex values, conversion is required before math.